# How to use ruby regexp to substitute string with a "callback function"-like manipulation

Tags: ruby, regex, callback

I have the samples lines, and I want to substitute the leading `#`s with `=`s. (The first two lines)
But in`string.gsub!(/^#+\w/, "")`, I can not get the number of `#` which I want to substitute.

In javascript, I could use a callback function with the `replace` method, but how could I archive this Ruby?

```
##Command-line Tool
###Installment
This is a '#'.
```

The expected result:

```
==Command-line Tool
===Installment
This is a '#'.
```

Comment: So do you want to replace all the # in your string or only specific occurances? IF you want to replace all the # present, then you could simple do myString.gsub("#", "=")

Comment: Not really, only the leading one, and as the leading one varies from one to the other, I need to count them in the substitution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a callback block function to the gsub method, probably. I am not sure what you had in mind but could be something like

```
s.gsub(/^(#+)\w+/) {|m| m.gsub("#", "=") }
```

Comment: Thanks, one question. does `m` means the one match? ?

Comment: the block argument is the match yes, but in the block, if you want, you can access the perl-ish match variables  (`$1`, `$\`` etc). More infos at http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub